# Python curses getting x and y

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

Okay I am writing a python application using curses and I am trying to center my text in a terminal window from the documentation you can get the x and y using this

```
curses.LINES and curses.COLS
```

I got this from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

I guess they return the x and y as a integer

Here is how I am doing this

`screen.addstr(curses.LINES, curses.COLS, 'Please enter a number...', curses.color_pair(1))`

but when I run the program i get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
                                    File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
                                                                             main()
     File "main.py", line 47, in main
                                         screen.addstr(curses.LINES/2, curses.COLS/2, 'Please enter a number...', curses.color_pair(1))
                                                       TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

I am dividing by 2 to get the center but it keeps throwing the error

Comment: In python 3, dividing an integer by 2 gives you a float rather than an int. Try using `//` (integer division) instead of `/` (float division).

Comment: that worked but it is not centering the text

Comment: Because you are not taking the length of the text itself into account.  What you are doing now is centering the _start_ of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You not only have to calculate the center of the `screen` but also move the starting point half the length of the text to the left.  So the center of the text and the center of the screen fall onto the same coordinate.

```
text = 'Please enter a number...'
screen.addstr(
    curses.LINES // 2,
    curses.COLS // 2 - len(text) // 2,
    text,
    curses.color_pair(1)
)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without making multiple text strings

Comment: @112madgamer What do you mean by _making multiple text strings_? There is just one string in that answer.

Comment: @112madgamer I still don't get the question in the comment. And as this seems to be a different question than this one, maybe start a new question.

Comment: @112madgamer And maybe compare the code in my answer with yours. As already said, there's just one literal string in my answer. Your code has the literal string `'Please enter a number...'` twice.

Comment: Okay check the same link again I want the Print happy birthday Outpute date and the rest centered two. I don't want a string for each one if that is possible

Comment: @112madgamer I still don't get what you are after exactly, but again, that seems like a new question to me.

Comment: Okay is there a way to apply - len() to '4 - Exit' in the function without creating a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108299/discussion-between-blackjack-and-112madgamer).